# Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, json

I insert PHP array to mySql using `json_encode`method like this :

`["11","10","4"]`

Now I need to convert to php array:

```
$me = ["11","10","4"];
$you = json_decode($me, true);
echo $you;
```

But in result I see :
`Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 5`

How do fix this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$me` isn't a string. You should simply encapsulate it in single-quotes to change this.

```
$me = '["11","10","4"]';
$you = json_decode($me);
print_r($you);  // becasue its now a PHP array, 
                // copy/paste will get you every time
```

Comment: Dont need the `true` unless you are converting an object into an array. A rather fruitless thing to do in my opinion but horses for courses.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is true, I merely copy/pasted the original code and applied my fix. I've edited my answer to remove that parameter.

Comment: Not naggin, just felt like a comment I could not force back in its box

Comment: @GeoffAtkins: not work :`Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 5
Array`

Comment: @Perspolis You surely should have seen that one yourself

Comment: No - you're right I should have been paying closer attention.